# Converting a single user application to a multi user application

Tags: c, data-structures, shared-memory

I am working on a legacy C application that is currently single user. I want to modify it so that it is multi user.

The current application makes uses user permissions to load relevant data (for the current user), into shared memory. I want to implement a dictionary like structure in shared memory so that relevant data is stored using a unique user key - however, a naive dictionary structure will result in the data held in the dictionary being duplicated, as all users share the same data, but are only allowed restricted 'views' of the data, based on their role/permission.

Can someone suggest a data structure thst provides the 'look up' behaviour of a dictionary, yet avoids duplicity of data that a 'naive' dictionary would inevitably result in?

Note: My application is in C, so I cannot use classes, I will need a data structure that can be implemented in C, and stored in shared memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one global dictionary and user specific indicies to its entries.

Comment: I may be missing something here; I don't see how the global dictionary approach avoids the duplicated data problem - could you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: The inserting functionality should check whether the data to be inserted is already in the dic.

Comment: ok, but that introduces two 'problems': **1** I'll need to implement a mechanism to 'rejoin' the data on reads from the dict  **2** A performance overhead due to 'rejoining data' on reads. Currently, the app is lightning fast because it directly sets up shared memory with data for one user. I would like to keep to that performance level (as close as possible)

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: You either get speed **or** less data redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux the system call unshare is used to implement the multi user support.